# AJAX request for array from C# server

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, httprequest

I created a simple server using C# HTTP Listener, and I think I understand how clients(javascript) request things that are in the server(C#). I managed to request html pages, ico file for favicon, txt files, png etc. Now If I want to request from the server using Ajax primitives like integers, floats, strings, arrays, matrices(2d arrays), I couldn't find the mime for that. For example. I need for the client to request a carefully computed 1D Array from C# and I settled on this which. In the C# server I write to a .txt file the array in this format:
`a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 ... an`

using this code:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("list.txt")) { 
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        //Computation algorithm for the list
        writer.Write(myInt.ToString() + " "); 
    }
 
}
```

And in the JS, I request the .txt file and split by the space:

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Initialize the request
    xhr.open("GET", '/list.txt');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {

            var response = xhr.responseText;
            var arr = response.split(" ");
            
        }
    }
```

It works, however it is feels a bit overkill to create a txt file containing some data, that could be sent directly as it is stored in the C# server's RAM. Can JS request from the C# server without storing it in a text.

Comment: Why can't you just send the string?

Comment: If it is possible to send a string from C# server to AJAX I don't know how

Comment: The C# HTTP listener code is more relevant to your question than the Javascript code.  Within the HTTP listener, there must be code that picks apart the URL to determine the server side file to return (in your case `list.txt`), and it is in the vicinity of this code that you will need to add logic to respond to a custom GET for `list.txt`.  Eg, if the server sees a fetch for `myList`, rather than seek and return a file named `myList`, perform your calculations to generate the list, and send the results back through the client socket connection...

Comment: In the http listener code. I get the url and if the url is: `192.168.0.1/index.html` I response with the html, if the url is `192.168.0.1/favicon.ico` I response with the ico file. I think what you are saying is that I need to create a special case for returning an array or anything, for example: `if(request.url==".../LIST"){//give the integer list array converted to byte array as response}` And In the ajax, I request the `/LIST` url and the server will know that this is a data request, not a file request. Am I right?